# fullcalendar coliding events

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the `FullCalendar` plugin to display a lot of events. It seems though that sometimes these events are placed on top of each other like in the picture below... Anyone knows how to prevent it?

http://imageshack.us/photo/f/707/bugqp.png/

The feed:

```
events: [
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 0, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 2, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 0, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 2, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 30),
    allDay: false
},

{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 1, 00),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 3, 00),
    allDay: false
},

{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 1, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 3, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 50),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 50),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 4, 30),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 6, 30),
    allDay: false
},
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 00),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 00),
    allDay: false
},

{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 50),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 50),
    allDay: false
},

{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 2, 50),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 4, 50),
    allDay: false
},      
{
    title: 'One event',
    start: new Date(y, m, d, 4, 00),
    end:  new Date(y, m, d, 6, 00),
    allDay: false
}               
]
```

Comment: For anyone interested, I started a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMtEJ/2/), seems like it might not be possible though, at least without major manipulation

Comment: Defining static width does not solve the collision problem. So far I've been playing with function stackSegs(segs) in fullcalendar.js but cant get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

There's an AgendaView option for that introduced in [v1.6.4](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/changelog.md#v164-2013-09-01). From [the docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/):

#### slotEventOverlap 1.6.4

Determines if timed events in agenda view should visually overlap.

```
Boolean, default: true
```

When set to true (the default), events will overlap each other. At most half of each event will be obscured.

When set to false, there will be absolutely no overlapping.